# How to check the load when there is different Database sql server, different application server with the help of jmeter

Tags: database, jmeter, perfmon

I have followed the steps to get the load test results with PERFMON using the below-given land got the results.

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test

Now, I want to get the stats of the sql server as well as the application server while running my load test. In this case, my DB is running on a different server and my application is running on a different server and there is a 3rd server(client machine) on which my JMeter is running and communicate with both servers in parallel.

How to run load test in this case when a separate DB server is running.

Thanks and looking forward.

Answer (score 0):

Just install 2 [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) instances onto these 2 machines and you will be able to collect metrics of your choice with a single PerfMon Metrics Collector

[image]

Also be informed that it is also possible to collect server-side performance metrics without having to install the Server Agent (given there is SSH connectivity between JMeter and the system under test) using [SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener)